# Download from multiple backup apt repository in ubuntu

Tags: apt, repository, amazon-ec2, apt-mirror

I have AWS auto scaling group which scales out in peak hours. I'm facing unhealthy instances due to do AWS's apt servers being unresponsive sometimes.

```
 Err:68 http://ap-northeast-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 python-apt-common all 2.0.0ubuntu0.20.04.7
  503  Service Unavailable 
Err:69 http://ap-northeast-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 python3-apt amd64 2.0.0ubuntu0.20.04.7
  503  Service Unavailable
Err:70 http://ap-northeast-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 ubuntu-release-upgrader-core all 1:20.04.38
  503  Service Unavailable 
Err:71 http://ap-northeast-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 update-manager-core all 1:20.04.10.10
  503  Service Unavailable 
Err:72 http://ap-northeast-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 python3-distupgrade all 1:20.04.38
  503  Service Unavailable
Err:73 http://ap-northeast-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 python3-update-manager all 1:20.04.10.10
  503  Service Unavailable
```

This does not happen every time but once in a while.

**I'm trying to use multiple apt repositories in Ubuntu 20.04 so that when one fails, the packages will be downloaded from another. Is there any efficient way to do so?**

I tried making clone of aws's apt repository (ap-northeast-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ in my case) using apt-mirror. Then I uploaded it to S3 with cloudfront. Then I added the endpoints in sources.list file.

- When I use my clone's endpoint only it works fine.
- When I use public repository and clone repository at the same time it works fine
  when both of them are available.
- When I make clone unavailable by disabling cloudfront access, I get unhealthy instances again.

I want apt to use backup repository whenever main repository is down.
My `sources.list` file while using both repo looks like:

```
#clone
deb my-endpoint/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
deb my-endpoint/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
deb my-endpoint/ubuntu/ focal universe
deb my-endpoint/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe
deb my-endpoint/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
deb my-endpoint/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse
deb my-endpoint/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse

#public
deb http://ap-northeast-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
deb http://ap-northeast-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
deb http://ap-northeast-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
deb http://ap-northeast-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe
deb http://ap-northeast-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
deb http://ap-northeast-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse
deb http://ap-northeast-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse

#security
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse
```